# Remember me Status

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, customer-session

I've got a block that should be visible only for NOT LOGGED IN customers.
To check if a customer is logged in or not i'm using:

```
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
```

but, since i'm using **Remember me** functionality, it happens that a customer see everything in the site as if it were logged in and so even the specific block should not be visible, but it is.
How can I hide that block in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, don't knokw if is the only one is to check for the cookie.

```
<?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && !Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('persistent_shopping_cart')): ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The method `isLoggedIn()` on `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` checks if the user is logged in on the server side.

Using the "Remember Me" or not, **this method will return true if the user is logged in**.

Perhaps there are other parts of the code that is making it visible?

Just to be clear, when you said "Remember Me" functionality, this is the magento standard code, right?

UPDATE:

As clarified by @VivekKhandelwal, there is no "Remember me" functionality on standard Magento. Therefore your issue is coming from a third party extension that is installed in your website.

Comment: Actually, Magento don't provide remember me functionality by default. I think krybbio is using some external extension for achieving this. I would say instead of using a single function, try add one more condition to it. like, if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer->getId() )

Comment: remember me functionality is default magento functionality, maybe the right name is "Persistent Shopping Cart", "Remember me" is what you check at login step.

Comment: @VivekKhandelwal Thank you for clarifying this. I thought it has remember me functionality by default.

krybbio, I just checked. There really is no "Remember me" functionality on login/registration on both Magento 1.9 and Magento 1.4. Your problem is a third party extension bug.

Comment: @VernardLuz , no man, it is a dafault functionality. You can enable it in `System > Configuration > Clients >Persistent Shopping Cart`.
Anyway I found a solution that works checking for the persistent_shopping_cart cookie.

Comment: @krybbio Good for you!